# stemming words removal in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

am new to Haskell and functional programing..

my aim is to get a string from user and check whether there is any stemming words available in that string. if so i want to remove the stemming and return the string.

```
Eg: if input is :"He is fishing and catching"
    output is : "he is fish and catch"
```

i can do this in other languages. but i don't know how to do it in Haskell. do any one know how to solve this problem using Haskell..

```
checkstemming :: [String] -> [String]
checkstemming [] = []
checkstemming xs = foldr (++) [] ( [ drop x |x <- xs, x="ing"])
```

i tried, but i know its wrong. can anyone help me to sole this problem please..

Comment: Instead of `foldr (++) []` you can use `map`. You should also look at the `words` function, and the `isSuffixOf` function from the `Data.List` module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tackle one word at a time, this makes things much easier:

```
removeStemming :: String -> String
removeStemming []        = []
removeStemming (x:"ing") = [x]
removeStemming (x:xs)    = x : removeStemming xs

checkStemming :: [String] -> [String]
checkStemming = map removeStemming
```

Another way to do this is to use `isSuffixOf` from `Data.List`:

```
removeStemming :: String -> String
removeStemming xs
  | "ing" `isSuffixOf` xs = take (length xs - 3) xs
  | otherwise             = xs
```