# removing the stemming words using haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

i am new to haskell and functional programing..

my aim  is to remove the stemming words from the given string..

```
eg: input is : "he is fishing and catched two fish"
    output is : "he is fish and catch two fish"
```

i tried to do this with the following code. it removes only the "ed" and it does not remove "ing".

```
removeStemming :: String -> String
removeStemming xs
  | "ing" `isSuffixOf` xs = take (length xs - 3) xs
  | "ed"  `isSuffixOf` xs = take (length xs - 2) xs
  | otherwise             = xs
```

can anyone help me to fix this error. please..

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error. Could you show how you use `removeStemming`?

Comment: **FirstScript> removeStemming "he is fishing and catched"**
 result    **"he is fishing and catch"**

Comment: @Sathyabaman: you should first iterate over the words, use your "removeStemming" on those and then assemble the results. You should start with understanding how to do the first and third steps...

Comment: Your question is fine, but do note that in most Englishes, the past tense form/past participle of "catch" is "caught", and not \*"catched".  (This is part of why stemming is hard.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already said in the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20836136/1139697), that it gets easier if your tackling one word at a time:

> Tackle one word at a time, this makes things much easier:
>
> ```
> removeStemming :: String -> String
> removeStemming []        = []
> removeStemming (x:"ing") = [x]
> removeStemming (x:"ed")  = [x] --new, since ed wasn't part of the last question
> removeStemming (x:xs)    = x : removeStemming xs
> ```

If you have a look at the definition of `removeStemming`, you'll notice that it will remove only the *very last* stemming. Therefore, `removeStemming` is meant for a single word.

If you want to apply it onto many words, you need to apply it on every single word:

```
removeAllStemmings :: String -> String
removeAllStemmings = unwords . map removeStemming . words
```

After this you can use `removeAllStemmings "he is fishing and catched two fish"`.

Comment: bur once i implement that one.. this is the result i get.. **FirstScript> removeAllStemmings "he is catching and fishing"**
result is **"e s atch nd ish"**

Comment: @Sathyabaman: Well, your `removeStemming` implementation is wrong, let me fetch mine. Or at least I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: thank you Mr.Zeta.. now i understand that using "suffixof " is not a good idea i this type of situation. anyway thank you very much..

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are applying `removeStemming` to the entire string, when you want to apply it to each word.  You can do

```
> unwords $ map removeStemming $ words "he is fishing and catched two fish"
"he is fish and catch two fish"
```

The `words` function splits the string on whitespace and returns a list of all the words, and `unwords` performs the opposite action (note: in general `unwords . words` is not equivalent to `id`).  You can map your `removeStemming` function as it is to the output of `words text`, then join them back together with `unwords`

Answer (score 1):

If we wish to remove all "ing" and "ed", let's change Zeta answer such way:

```
removeStemming :: String -> String
removeStemming []                    = []
removeStemming ('i':'n':'g':' ':xs)  = removeStemming xs
removeStemming ('e':'d':' '    :xs)  = removeStemming xs
removeStemming "ing"                 = []
removeStemming "ed"                  = []
removeStemming (x:xs)                = x : removeStemming xs
```

I divided `removeStemming "ing"` and `removeStemming ('i':'n':'g':' ':xs)` if we don't want to reduce "ringing" to "r"

Comment: This will reduce `"ringing"` to "r".

Comment: @Zeta Agree )) I've changed the answer